# Action link in grid table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
           @Html.ActionLink("Подробней", "Details", new { id = item.id 
    }
```

But now I have grid:

```
<div class="code-cut">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{

    columns.Add(c => c.name).Titled(" name").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.created).Titled(" date").Filterable(true);
}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
</div>
```

How to add ActionLink to grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column and use `RenderValueAs`. Here is an approx example:

```
.RenderValueAs(
    model => Html.ActionLink("Подробней", "Details", new { id = c.id})
                 .ToHtmlString()
)
```